# Laravel Passport APi - Implicit grant

Tags: laravel, oauth-2.0, authorization

I want to build a spa via angularjs and use laravel as a api for the spa. Reading trough the docs of laravel passport i discovered that i need to use the implicit grant for this purpose. But i am not really sure in how it should work from front to back. I just want to have the ability to log in a user with a username and password and then just use it and i need some clarification on the process. This is what i want:

1. Log in with a user by a username and password via html/javascript to laravel (Angular) via an ajax request.
2. Get an access token to communicate with the api
3. Do some action in the spa that triggers a request to the api using the access token
4. Getting data back from the api in response to that request.

But what i see now with the implicit grant i a bit different than what i expect.

1. Log in to laravel via a default blade login form (did not create one using ajax yet)
2. Redirect to oauth/autorize like this

   ```
   Route::get('/redirect', function () {
   $query = http_build_query([
       'client_id' => 'client-id',
       'response_type' => 'token',
       'scope' => '',
   ]);

   return redirect('http://your-app.com/oauth/authorize?'.$query);
   ```

   });
3. The redirect shows an approve or deny authorization request screen (this is not what i expect)
4. When i approve the request, the browser redirects me to the redirect uri that is specified in the oAuth client database entry with the access token. And i should be able to.

What confuses me even more is the fact that i seem to need a new client for each laravel user. I expect to have 1 oauth client representing my spa that can access the laravel users. Could you please clarify this?

Comment: - i think you should use password grant type, and as we have always use password grant type for such authentication and authorization.

Comment: But that would be considered dangerous as the password grant type will return an refresh token that you would need to store securely on the client side (browser). And that's just not possible right?

Comment: yes, you can store on client side in cookies or storage, and also u can return custom things.

Comment: No you cannot. Because if you put it in cookies or in storage, other users of your computer could retrieve the refresh token if they want and act on behalf of you. And there is also, if i am correct the risk involved where another site could read your cookie or local storage and steal your refresh token via that way to.

So in short: It is not secure to store refresh and access tokens safely on the client side. And therefore i think, the password grant is not an option for a SPA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are going to use a password grant in a JavaScript application then you must use a server side proxy to do the authentication and secure both client_secret and the refresh token.

The proxy manages the whole api communication process or just the authentication part and returns a short lived access_token . Authentication state is managed via a server session. Some requests must be protected from CSRF exploits depending on your implementation since most implementations use a cookie.

Otherwise use an implicit grant to authenticate your app. (See links below for more info)

https://auth0.com/docs/api-auth/tutorials/implicit-grant

https://oauth2.thephpleague.com/authorization-server/implicit-grant/

You can refresh your access token using silent authentication as described here
https://auth0.com/docs/api-auth/tutorials/silent-authentication

NB: In most cases refresh tokens do not expire, that's a big NO for Frontend storage.

Client Secret should always be kept secret.

## Edit (2020)

It's now 2020 and a lot has changed in the web security world.

There are known vulnerabilities with implicit grant especially since your access_token can be intercepted mid-flight and redirected to another server.
It's now recommended to use PKCE flow instead of implicit grant

Okta has a very nice article and video regarding this [Is the OAuth 2.0 Implicit Flow Dead?](https://developer.okta.com/blog/2019/05/01/is-the-oauth-implicit-flow-dead)

Laravel has also released a much simpler alternative [Laravel Sanctum](https://laravel.com/docs/master/sanctum) I suggest you have a look at it as it uses secure HTTP only cookies for access token storage and also implements CSRF protection out of the box

Comment: I've solved it by building a php proxy. It intercepts all requests and does have a look at the controller it is trying to reach. If the controller is of a certain interface type i do a request using guzzle by adding the client id and secret and adding the authorisation token. The response i then sent back to the javascript frontend. What i do and probable must not do is store the authorization and refresh token in the clients browser as a cookie. But in encrypted form. Is there a better way to do it? A session cookie is just as vulnerable i think since it refers to a session with tokens?

Comment: My client secret and client id are stored server side b.t.w

Comment: For anyone looking for laravel Airlock, it is now called Sanctum "due to a trademark dispute regarding the name "Airlock"". See here: https://blog.laravel.com/airlock-renamed-to-sanctum